# Error: Java chaincode is work-in-progress and disabled in Fabric 1.1

Tags: java, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I wrote chaincode in Java and am trying to install it on a fabric 1.1.0 network, but getting following error while installing chaincode.

**Error: Java chaincode is work-in-progress and disabled**

I am using `peer chaincode install -l java` to install the chain code.

Following are the fabric images that I am using
[image]

All are fabric 1.1.0 images.
Though its said that fabric 1.1.0 supports java chaincode, don't know why am getting this error.

Answer (score 0):

Right at the moment Java chaincode is an experimental feature and disabled by default, leading to the message you have posted above.

In order to enable it you need to recompile fabric with experimental build tag enabled.

**NOTE**: There is also work in progress to make it available rather keeping experimental.